# Good resource available to begin developing a mobile website

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

We currently have a high traffic web site, so are relatively comfortable with web technologies (although we are primarily java developers), and we are wanting to create a mobile version of our site.

Can anyone suggest good online resources to get started?

**UPDATE**

The current site is a basic administration site for a regular user of a certain telecommunications service, the service allows you to add signatures to SMS, send group messages, view your account etc.. At present the site uses JSPs.

I was sort of looking for a more bare bones set of resources, tutorials, standards.

This [w3 standards site](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/) is the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I would describe the vote to close fairly contentious so to not provide a comment is just lame (particularly with a down vote)

Comment: Here are 2 criteria I think this question falls into extracted from faq: software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession. I would suggest edition to faq if this is to be closed

Comment: Upvoted back to 0 because i hate down-voters who don't explain themselves!

Comment: What is your current site, what does it do and what do you need a mobile version to do?  Some more info will get your more specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile is a good starting point.

You can find it here http://jquerymobile.com/

Also comes prepackaged with Dreamweaver CS5.5.

Definitely worth a shot at trying it out! :)